# How to understand Tornado's dict in the URL handler?

Tags: python, tornado

The code snippets comes from Python Tornado framework. Given the following definitions, how to understand the function call.

definition:

```
class Application(object):
    def __init__(self, handlers=None, default_host="", transforms=None, wsgi=False, **settings):
        ...
```

function call:

```
Application([(r'/user/(.*)', ProfileHandler, dict(database=database)),])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets break it down step by step:

`Application([(r'/user/(.*)', ProfileHandler, dict(database=database)),])` - is a constructor call.

`[(r'/user/(.*)', ProfileHandler, dict(database=database)),]` - is the first parameter named `handlers`.

`(r'/user/(.*)', ProfileHandler, dict(database=database))` - is specific handler, described by tuple of: route regex, handler class, any additional options for handler.

So `dict(database=database)` is additional options for first handler (3rd member of handler tuple). It seems to specify database to use.

Result of `dict(database=database)` will be the same as `{'database': database}`. You are allowed to pass any arbitrary keyword arguments to it to build your dictionary (example: `dict(database=database, hello='world', environment='development', etc='test')`, and so on).

`dict` keyword is an actual dictionary type name, so this is call of dictionary's constructor.